# php if or codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, simple-html-dom

i have started using https://github.com/Lukeas14/codeigniter_crawler for codeigniter, and it works great.
One problem, in the librari, on this function for example:

```
public function get_description(){
    if(!$page_description = $this->dom->find('head meta[name=Description]', 0)){
        return false;
    }

    return $this->clean_text($page_description->content);
}
```

this will search in the Description and show the tags, but if the html file has description written with 'small d' it wont find it, so im trying to do something like this but i cannot manage to make it work.
my attempt :

```
public function get_description(){
    if(!$page_description = $this->dom->find('head meta[name=Description]', 0) || !$page_description = $this->dom->find('head meta[name=description]', 0) ){
        return false;
    }

    return $this->clean_text($page_description->content);
}
```

Any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions need to be wrapped by brackets. But to make your `if` statement more readable I suggest the following code:

```
public function get_description(){
    $page_description = $this->dom->find('head meta[name=Description]', 0) ?: $this->dom->find('head meta[name=description]', 0);

    return $page_description ? $this->clean_text($page_description->content) : false;
}
```